# How to create a light trail in ImageMagik command line - Comparing brightest parts of two images

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I've got a tiff sequence of a light moving around in a dark room, the goal is to write out a new sequence in which the light forms a trail.

I'm thinking something like - the current frame and the most recent new frame are compared, whichever pixel is brighter gets put in the next new frame.

Is this possible with ImageMagick? Can anyone suggest some commands to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking the brightest pixel at each location:

```
magick frame*.tif -evaluate-sequence max trail.tif
```